# Docker Compose up Throws SSL error using Docker Machine

Tags: docker, openssl, docker-compose, docker-machine

I connected my Virtualbox VM to my docker machine.And when i do docker-compose up from docker machine I am getting this following Error.

```
ERROR: SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.4.20', port=2376): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.22/info (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname '192.168.4.20' doesn't match 'localhost'",),))
```

Comment: Googling your error returned 2 results from the docker github : [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3393) and [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2431). Have a look at the solutions provided and tell us if it works for you.

Comment: I have tried them but none of them worked for me

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am experiencing the same and none of the mentioned results work for me either.

Comment: yes issue with the ssl certificates.

Comment: how did you solved ?

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I just had this. Apparently, Docker Compose is not using the correct TLS version. You can fix this by having the following environment variable:

`COMPOSE_TLS_VERSION=TLSv1_2`

Here's the original link: https://stackify.com/docker-environment-variables/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I could resolve renewing the certificate.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.99.100', port=2376): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.30/networks/docker_default 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))


$ docker network ls
error during connect: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.40/networks: x509: 
certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

**To fix:**

```
$ docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs


$ docker-compose up -d
Starting couchdb-dev   ... done
Starting consul-dev    ... done
Starting postgres-dev  ... done
Starting zipkin-dev    ... done
Starting rabbitmq-dev  ... done
Starting oracle-dev    ... done
Starting cassandra-dev ... done
```

**Works!**

*ps: I got this error after change the hour on clock from computer*